# C#:Java error in .NET 2.0 framework

Tags: c#-2.0

I`m getting following error in my application,

Error:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'java.util.Locale' threw an exception. ---> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load DLL 'vjsnativ': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'vjsnativ': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at com.ms.vjsharp.windowing.win32.UnsafeWin32Calls.GetLocaleInfo<PInvokeHelper>vjsnativ(Int32 lcid, Int32 lctype, StringBuilder lpLCData, Int32 cchData)
   at com.ms.vjsharp.windowing.win32.UnsafeWin32Calls.GetLocaleInfo(Int32 lcid, Int32 lctype, StringBuffer lpLCData, Int32 cchData)
   at java.util.Locale..ctor(CultureInfo ci, String language, String ctryRgn, String variant)
   at java.util.Locale..ctor(String languageCode, String ctryRgnCode)
   at java.util.Locale..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError.checkAndThrowException(Throwable thrown)
   at java.util.Locale..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at java.util.Locale.getDefault()
   at com.ms.vjsharp.lang.StringImpl.toUpperCase(String mrString)
   at com.vividsolutions.jts.io.WKTReader.getNextWord(StreamTokenizer tokenizer)
   at com.vividsolutions.jts.io.WKTReader.readGeometryTaggedText(StreamTokenizer tokenizer)
   at com.vividsolutions.jts.io.WKTReader.read(Reader reader)
   at com.vividsolutions.jts.io.WKTReader.read(String wellKnownText)
```

i`m using .net 2.0, windows xp os. Please check and let me know your answers and suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Do you really *need* to use J#? It was discontinued rather a long time ago.

Comment: why downvote? some people are stuck integrating with legacy third party libraries -this post has just been a big help to me

Answer (score 0):

You can find and copy vjsnativ.dll to your applications directory or you can add this code before you call any J# code.

```
// This problem started with .NET 4
if (Environment.Version.Major >= 4)
{
    string dllpath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), @"..\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727");
    dllpath = Path.GetFullPath(dllpath);
    LoadLibrary(Path.Combine(dllpath, "vjsnativ.dll"));
}
// J# code should work now
```

Comment: Aside from LoadLibrary not being defined, Assembly.LoadFile gives the following error for this file: The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131018)

Comment: So make LoadLibrary defined: [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);